# Open route from two different origin routes

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

In my app, I have a `HomePage` that displays a few selected posts and a `PostListPage`. From both pages I open posts.

I have this route structure.

```
GoRouter(
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: "/",
      builder: (context, state) => HomePage(),
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: "post/:id",
          builder: (context, state) => // ...
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: "posts",
          builder: (context, state) => PostListPage()
        )
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

When I open a post one the home page with `GoRouter.go`, it works as intended but when I open a post from the PostListPage, the back button routes back to the HomePage, when it should route back to the PostListPage.

How can I fix this?

I know I can use `GoRouter.push` instead, however, with push, on web, the route is not reflected in the URL and therefore, when refreshing the browser on a PostPage, it starts the app at the HomePage.

I could use the `GoRouter.optionURLReflectsImperativeAPIs`option to avoid this URL issue, but the docs say "It is strongly suggested against setting this value to true".

Comment: can you include full snippet, a gist/dartpad link will be easier. I think `.push`  does the job(url-changes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have a `post/:id` route from the home and the post list pages as well, you can add a child route under `posts`:

```
GoRouter(
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: "/",
      builder: (context, state) => HomePage(),
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: "post/:id",
          builder: (context, state) => // ...
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: "posts",
          builder: (context, state) => PostListPage(),
          // add this part, and implement the same builder
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              path: "post/:id",
              builder: (context, state) => // ...
            ),
          ]
        )
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

When navigating from home, use:

```
context.go('/post/123')
```

And from the post list:

```
context.go('/posts/post/123')
```

After this navigating back should word as intended.

This is a simple example that you can run in DartPad:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp.router(
        routerConfig: GoRouter(
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              path: "/",
              builder: (context, state) => Home(),
              routes: [
                GoRoute(
                  path: "post/:id",
                  builder: (context, state) =>
                      Post(id: state.pathParameters['id']),
                ),
                GoRoute(
                    path: "posts",
                    builder: (context, state) => Posts(),
                    routes: [
                      GoRoute(
                        path: "post/:id",
                        builder: (context, state) =>
                            Post(id: state.pathParameters['id']),
                      )
                    ])
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
        theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47),
        ),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      );
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Column(children: [
        Text('Home', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayMedium),
        TextButton(
          child: const Text('Posts'),
          onPressed: () => context.go('/posts'),
        ),
        TextButton(
          child: const Text('Post 123'),
          onPressed: () => context.go('/post/123'),
        ),
        TextButton(
          child: const Text('Post 456'),
          onPressed: () => context.go('/post/456'),
        )
      ]);
}

class Posts extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Column(children: [
        Text('Posts', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayMedium),
        TextButton(
          child: const Text('Post 123'),
          onPressed: () => context.go('/post/123'),
        ),
        TextButton(
          child: const Text('Post 456'),
          onPressed: () => context.go('/posts/post/456'),
        ),
        TextButton(
          child: const Text('Back'),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
        )
      ]);
}

class Post extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? id;
  const Post({required this.id});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Column(children: [
        Text(
          'Post $id',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
        ),
        TextButton(
          child: const Text('Back'),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
        )
      ]);
}
```

Comment: I have a similar example. But in my app in GoRoute "post/:id" I have 3 more nested children routes. Let's say from the post itself I can go to the pages to read about the author, to see the info about the post, etc. Does it mean that I have to duplicate all the code for "post/:id" and 3 children routes (about 50 loc) twice in the code? Don't we have other ways to do it except pushing manually? Thank you

Comment: @Sander If you need different paths you have to define the route hierarchy in `GoRouter` config. The code does not need to be duplicated, you can build the same type of widget in different routes.